plots not generating all the samples and leave excess vertical space
I'm pretty new to machine learning. I was using fetch_olivetti_faces as my database for practice in my coding class. I ran the code, and it worked since I was following the teacher's instructions. However, the plots seemed to be leaving out some spaces and only displayed one sample, while other students were able to generate a whole page of samples. I suppose this might not be a coding issue, but rather a software or settings problem. What could have possibly happened? Thanks!!
PS. here are some reference photos.And I am using Spyder.And heres the codes:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces


model = 'decision tree'

k = 2

tree_max_depth = 5


faces = fetch_olivetti_faces()
data = faces.data
targets = faces.target


print("The shape of my data is: ", data.shape)
n_pixels = data.shape[1] 

train = data[targets < 30]
test = data[targets >= 30]
print(train.shape)


X_train = train[:, : (n_pixels + 1) // 2]

y_train = train[:, n_pixels // 2 :]

X_test = test[:, : (n_pixels + 1) // 2]
y_test = test[:, n_pixels // 2 :]
print("we are using a", model, "model")

if model == 'extra trees':
    estimator = ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators=10, max_features=32, random_state=0)
elif model == 'decision tree':
    estimator = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=tree_max_depth, random_state=0)
elif model == "knn":
    estimator = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k)


estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)


estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_test_predict = estimator.predict(X_test)
print("X_test shape:", X_test.shape)
print("y_test shape:", y_test.shape)

estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)


n_faces = 6

image_shape = (64, 64)
n_cols = 2

plt.figure(figsize=(2.0 * n_cols, 2.26 * n_faces))
plt.suptitle("Face completion with " + model + " regression: \ntesting set",
size=16)
for i in range(n_faces):
 true_face = np.hstack((X_test[i], y_test[i]))
if i:
 sub = plt.subplot(n_faces, n_cols, i * n_cols + 1)
else:
 sub = plt.subplot(n_faces, n_cols, i * n_cols + 1, title="true faces")
 sub.axis("off")
sub.imshow(
true_face.reshape(image_shape), cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation="nearest"
)
completed_face = np.hstack((X_test[i], y_test_predict[i]))
sub = plt.subplot(n_faces, n_cols, i * n_cols + 2)
sub.axis("off")
sub.imshow(
completed_face.reshape(image_shape),
cmap=plt.cm.gray,
interpolation="nearest",
)
plt.show()


y_train_predict = estimator.predict(X_train)
plt.figure(figsize=(2.0 * n_cols, 2.26 * n_faces))
plt.suptitle("Face completion with " + model + " regression: \ntraining set",
size=16)
for i in range(n_faces):
 true_face = np.hstack((X_train[i], y_train[i]))
if i:
 sub = plt.subplot(n_faces, n_cols, i * n_cols + 1)
else:
 sub = plt.subplot(n_faces, n_cols, i * n_cols + 1, title="true faces")
sub.axis("off")
sub.imshow(
true_face.reshape(image_shape), cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation="nearest"
)
completed_face = np.hstack((X_train[i], y_train_predict[i]))
sub = plt.subplot(n_faces, n_cols, i * n_cols + 2)
sub.axis("off")
sub.imshow(
completed_face.reshape(image_shape),
cmap=plt.cm.gray,
interpolation="nearest",
)
plt.show()

this is the plot that I could only generate 1 sample
I dont know where the problems were, i dont know where to start looking at, the code ran perfectly, oly the plots wernt working as intended.

I think you need to move your if loops inside your for loops.

ah! yes thats the problem! thankyou.
